# How to determine whether the browser process runs in foreground?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

Is it possible to determine whether the browser process itself runs in the background or in the foreground using Javascript? 
I am looking for a method that will let me know if the browser process is in the foreground/background in the OS level (For example if the `chrome.exe` process is on foreground in the OS).

I noticed that using the Page Visibility WebAPI I can determine whether my tab is in focus, but actually if the tab is in focus but the browser itself is not it still considered as visible.

Clarification - my goal is to update specific data on my client-side just, and just if, the user is for sure watching the browser at the moment. In other words, I have to check that the specific tab in the browser is active (did it with Page Visibility API), and that the browser itself is on top of all the other processes that running on the machine.

Thanks

Comment: Your use case is still unclear, kindly provide some more context?

Comment: @Sarthak I edited the question, provided additional example.

Comment: Just your browser might run several processes in parallel, from there what do you call the foreground or the background. Even when your window is not the active one, it's still a foreground/background process depending only on how it has be called initially. I invite you to clarify your issue, for instance you may add a bit of background as to "why" you want to know what you want to know so it's clearer to us what we need to search for.

Comment: @Kaiido added a clarification

Comment: What about you ask for an user action? Buttons have been created for this kind of use case. If you want it to be trasparent you can listen for other events like mousemove etc.

Comment: Button is not an option since I want it to be transparent for the user. 
As for the mousemove events, this was my old solution but had some edge cases that this solution didn't solve

Comment: Chrome on macOS seems to properly send the visibility change event when the browser itself loses focus — is this different on Windows?

Comment: @JoshLee Are you talking about `visibilitychange` event? If so, it changes just if the browser minimized. If, for example, the end-user opens an explorer process that hides the browser it still considered as "visible"

Comment: @GMe Yes, on macos, the event fires when the window is fully covered by another: https://copper-watcher.glitch.me